# How to make eaten numbers follow last eaten number

Tags: python, list

I want to make the eaten number to become some sort of 'head' of snake, and the last number follows that head. Picture example:

[image: Picture example]

This is beggining of program. 0 is the head of my snake. If snake goes right, and right, and right again - it goes on the number 1. I want him to 'eat' this 1 and replace its head for that number, so 0 would be behind him.

[image: Explanation]

```
def GiveTab(tab):
    x = 0
    while x < len(tab):
        print(tab[x])
        x+=1

tab = [['0', '.', '1', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '2', '.', '.'],
['.', '.', '.', '1', '3'],
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
['5', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

GiveTab(tab)
snake = '0'
snakeRow = 0
snakeColumn = 0
        
HelpCount = 0
while HelpCount != 10:

    order = input('Give order: ')
    order = order.upper()
    order = order.split()
    if len(order) == 3:

        if tab[int(order[1])-1][int(order[2])-1] == '.':
            print(-1)
        else:
            print(int(order[int(order[1])-1][int(order[2])-1]))

    elif order[0] == 'R':
        tab[snakeRow][snakeColumn], tab[snakeRow][snakeColumn+1]  = tab[snakeRow][snakeColumn+1], snake # tffffff           
        snakeColumn+=1     
        GiveTab(tab)
       
    elif order[0] == 'L':
        tab[snakeRow][snakeColumn], tab[snakeRow][snakeColumn-1]  = tab[snakeRow][snakeColumn-1], snake
        snakeColumn-=1
        GiveTab(tab)
    elif order[0] == 'U':
        tab[snakeRow][snakeColumn], tab[snakeRow-1][snakeColumn]  = tab[snakeRow-1][snakeColumn], snake
        snakeRow-=1
        GiveTab(tab)
    elif order[0] == 'D':
        tab[snakeRow][snakeColumn], tab[snakeRow+1][snakeColumn]  = tab[snakeRow+1][snakeColumn], snake
        snakeRow+=1
        GiveTab(tab)
    HelpCount+=1
```

**IN THIS EXAMPLE**

0 - head of that snake just replaces number 1. I want it to replace its head for that 1 like in the example above.
How?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need code that moves all the snake's content with one position. Therefore you need to keep track of the coordinates that are part of the snake -- not just the last position. Also avoid code repetition, and try to deal with a move in one common way.

I didn't quite get the input format, so I just limited the valid input to the 4 direction letters and "Q" to quit:

```
def GiveTab(tab):
    for row in tab:
        print(" ".join(row))

tab = [
    ['0', '.', '1', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '2', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '1', '3'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['5', '.', '.', '.', '.']
]

snake = [(0, 0)]
        
while True:
    GiveTab(tab)
    move = input('Give order: ').upper()
    if move == "Q":
        print("thanks for playing")
        break
    if not move in "URDL":
        print("invalid move")
        continue
    i = "URDL".index(move)
    drow, dcol = ((-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1))[i]
    nextrow = snake[0][0] + drow
    nextcol = snake[0][1] + dcol
    if not (0 <= nextrow < len(tab)) or not (0 <= nextcol < len(tab[0])):
        print("invalid move")
        continue
    snake.insert(0, (nextrow, nextcol))
    if tab[nextrow][nextcol] == '.':  # need to move the whole snake
        for (nextrow, nextcol), (prevrow, prevcol) in zip(snake, snake[1:]):
            tab[nextrow][nextcol] = tab[prevrow][prevcol]
        delrow, delcol = snake.pop()
        tab[delrow][delcol] = '.'
```

Comment: That code is my lifesaver! I didn't quite explain what Z was for in my code. It was to check if on certain given index of row and column is any color. If yes - print this color, if not return -1. But I'll figure it out. Thank you.